# MongoDB Query to find details of person with 3 Transactions in One Day

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here I have this MongoDB Implementation :

```
db={
  CUSTOMER: [
    {
      "CID": "C1",
      "CNAME": "Mark"
    },
    {
      "CID": "C2",
      "CNAME": "Chris"
    },
    {
      "CID": "C3",
      "CNAME": "James"
    }
  ],
  ACCOUNT: [
    {
      "ANO": 1,
      "Amount": 1000,
      "CID": 1
    },
    {
      "ANO": 2,
      "Amount": 350,
      "CID": 2
    },
    {
      "ANO": 3,
      "Amount": 450,
      "CID": 1
    },
    {
      "ANO": 4,
      "Amount": 360,
      "CID": 3
    },
    {
      "ANO": 5,
      "Amount": 800,
      "CID": 3
    }
  ],
  TRANSACTIONS: [
    {
      "TID": "T1",
      "ANO": 1,
      "Amount": 100,
      "TDATE": new Date("2005-03-22")
    },
    {
      "TID": "T2",
      "ANO": 3,
      "Amount": 350,
      "TDATE": new Date("2005-03-22")
    },
    {
      "TID": "T3",
      "ANO": 1,
      "Amount": 450,
      "TDATE": new Date("2005-03-22")
    },
    {
      "TID": "T4",
      "ANO": 2,
      "Amount": 360,
      "TDATE": new Date("2005-03-22")
    },
    {
      "TID": "T5",
      "ANO": 1,
      "Amount": 800,
      "TDATE": new Date("2005-03-22")
    }
  ]
}
```

Here a customer can have multiple accounts.

There is a reference between **[ Account(CID)-->CUSTOMER(CID) ]**

Another Reference is between **[ TRANSACTIONS(ANO) --> ACCOUNT(ANO) ]**

According to given Data , Only Customer C1 has 3 transections in a same date so Output should be like

"CID":"C1",
"CNAME":"MARK"

Note:- In case C1 has done 3 transactions in a day multiple times then i have to show his name Only one time , so DISTINCT Use will also be there.

***PLEASE CHECK DEMO : https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zhe6HjldyN0***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use two `$lookup` stages for each collections to refer and make use of the `pipeline` option of `$lookup` to apply the required logics.

```
db.CUSTOMER.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {  // <-- Lookup data from `ACCOUNT` collection
      "from": "ACCOUNT",
      "let": {  // <-- `let` allows us to store a key-value in `CUSTOMER` collection to a variable and allows it to be used on `lookup-Pipeline` option
        "cId": {  // <-- creating variable `cId` which is `CID` key-value in `CUSTOMER` collection 
          "$toInt": {  // <-- Converting string `1` to integer 1 since `CID` are stored as integer in `ACCOUNT` collection
            "$replaceOne": {  // <-- Since we have to convert `C1` to `1`, we are replacing the first occurance of `C` Character with empty string `""`
              input: "$CID",
              find: "C",  // <-- Character to find
              replacement: ""  // <-- Character to replace the first occurance of found character passed in `find` parameter
            }
          },
        }
      },
      "pipeline": [  // <-- Allows us to perform Aggregation query on looke-up matched records
        {
          "$match": {  // <-- Performing match operation on `ACCOUNT` collection
            "$expr": {  // <-- Making use of `$expr` stage, since matching using variable only works with `$expr` operator
              "$eq": [  // <-- Matching `CID` in `ACCOUNT` collection with `cId` variable initialized in `let`
                "$CID",  //<-- Reference keys with a single dollar sign prefix `$`
                "$$cId"  // <-- Always prefix variables with double dollar signs `$$`
              ]
            }
          },
        },
        {
          "$group": {  // <-- Groupping all the results from match stage to a single object where all the account numbers are pushed to an array `accNos` which will automatically filter out duplicated since they are push using `$addToSet`
            "_id": "$CID",  // <-- Keey to be groupped by
            "accNos": {
              "$addToSet": "$ANO"  // <-- Push `ANO` key-value to `accNos` array without any duplicate entries
            }
          },
        },
      ],
      "as": "matchedAcc"  // <-- `as` field indicated the new key name in which the aggregation results performed on `ACCOUNT` collection using lookup would appear as
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {  // <-- Performing `lookup` operation on `TRANSACTIONS` collection
      "from": "TRANSACTIONS",
      "let": {
        "accNosVar": {
          "$arrayElemAt": [  // <-- Fetch the first element in the array `matchedAcc` and object `accNos` in `matchedAcc` array
            "$matchedAcc.accNos",
            0  // <-- Fetch 1st element from the passed array (0th index)
          ]
        },
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$in": [
                "$ANO",
                "$$accNosVar"
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          "$group": {  // <-- Groupping by `TDATE` key and incrementing the `count` key
            "_id": "$TDATE",
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1  // <-- Increment existing value by 1
            },
          },
        },
        {
          "$match": {  // <-- Fetch only results which `count` value greater than or equal to 3
            "count": {
              "$gte": 3
            }
          },
        },
      ],
      "as": "matchedTransactions"
    },
  },
  {
    "$match": {  // <-- Filter only users who doesn;t have empty array. Only users with less than 3 transactions will have empty array
      "matchedTransactions": {
        "$ne": []
      }
    },
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EVh8fc5pLDU)

Comment: Please Explain The Logic Here. As i am beginner and trying to learn it..

Comment: Is it working as you expected? Or do you need any other changes? I will add the verbosity shortly.

Comment: Its Works as i wanted !! But i got scared of watching the Query .. Can u explain me the logic ?

Comment: @COURSEPRO I have added an explanation. Let me know if you want more clarity or explanation on a particular stage or operator. Tip: In MongoDB read each block from bottom to top to understand the flow.

Comment: Wonderful Explanation...Its clear now. Thanks

Comment: @hhharsha36 I have a similar query, can you please explain more on the second lookup. I'm unable to understand the part where you are fetching the first element in the array. How would it work for multiple accNos ? Thanks

Comment: @BE01 better ask as a question with your sample scenario so that it's easy to answer.